# Using certificate to identify that a pc is an authenticated user of a web application in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

can anyone help me with this? We need to make our web application available only for our branches with installed certificate generated by our server. Can it be done? And also, is there a way to  know that this pc is the one who accessed the site using the certificate? For example, I am a user from Manila Branch, and I'm using PC 1 with the certificate installed in it, is it possible for the system to identify the branch name using the certificate using vb.net? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it can be done. But if you want to ask _"how"_, then it might be  too broad to answer